TeleBot:Threaded polling exception: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: unsupported parse_mode
Код:
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(m):
  bot.send_message(m.chat.id, f'Приветсвую, {m.chat.first_name}! Я - бот, который поможет тебе в любой момент узнать актуальное расписание киберспортивных матчей! Для работы со мной используй кнопки!', parse_mode='markdown', reply_markup=kb_main)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def text(m):
  if m.text == 'Ближайший матч':
    def cs2():
      bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Ожидайте..')
      url = ('https://www.cybersport.ru/matches/cs2?date=future')
      wd = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
      wd.get(url)
      time.sleep(2)
      wd.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.item_uto6z').click()
      time.sleep(2)
      teams = wd.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'header.matchHeader_rKIvB').text
      matchtype = wd.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'matchFormat_0Oeci').text
      matchtime = wd.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'matchTime_ji1GK').text
      bot.send_message(m.chat.id, teams, matchtype, matchtime)

подскажите в чем проблема?
